# What is he best way how to get the short version of an article?

Tags: content-management-system

What do you think? What's the best way how to get from administratior the short version of an article (in CMS)?

I have 3 possibilies in my mind:

1) Create two textareas (WYSIWYG) fro the short and for the full version of article

2) The short version will be (for example) the first 100 words of article

3) To have one sepparator (like `<hr>`) and the short version will be the text from the beggining up to the sepparator (full version will be up to the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility would be to mix your first two ideas *(I don't quite like the third one, where the content cannot live without the excerpt)* :

- Use an aditionnal textarea for the exceprt,
- And if the user doesn't input anything in it, just use the first X words / sentences of the content.